# What can be the reason for a Stack canary watchpoint triggered (loopTask) on a https get() command?

Tags: arduino-ide, esp32, ethernet, http

I have a program that only do get and post to a controller via an ethernet port. My problem is that after a certain amount of loop in the program, i got this error:

```
Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (Unhandled debug exception). 
Debug exception reason: Stack canary watchpoint triggered (loopTask) 
Core  1 register dump:
PC      : 0x4012d2c8  PS      : 0x00060b36  A0      : 0x8012e241  A1      : 0x3ffc9cb0  
A2      : 0x3ffca070  A3      : 0x3ffca1ec  A4      : 0x3ffc9d70  A5      : 0x3ffca4bc  
A6      : 0x00000000  A7      : 0x00000018  A8      : 0x80130298  A9      : 0x3ffc9fd0  
A10     : 0x00000000  A11     : 0x00000000  A12     : 0x00000030  A13     : 0x3ffba06c  
A14     : 0x3ffc49ac  A15     : 0x00000008  SAR     : 0x0000001c  EXCCAUSE: 0x00000001  
EXCVADDR: 0x00000000  LBEG    : 0x40089a78  LEND    : 0x40089a83  LCOUNT  : 0x00000000  


Backtrace: 0x4012d2c5:0x3ffc9cb0 0x4012e23e:0x3ffca010 0x4012e2b3:0x3ffca030 0x4012e2ed:0x3ffca050 0x4012a3d4:0x3ffca070 0x40124912:0x3ffca170 0x40124a0a:0x3ffca1e0 0x40124a56:0x3ffca290 0x40124bd9:0x3ffca310 0x401208d5:0x3ffca330 0x401209b6:0x3ffca4e0 0x40120a95:0x3ffca500 0x40120b69:0x3ffca570 0x4011e28e:0x3ffca590 0x4011f22b:0x3ffca5c0 0x40121c38:0x3ffca610 0x40122911:0x3ffca650 0x401230c7:0x3ffca840 0x401210ef:0x3ffca9a0 0x40121336:0x3ffcaa00 0x4011be1d:0x3ffcaa20 0x40119881:0x3ffcaac0 0x401198bb:0x3ffcaae0 0x400d9af1:0x3ffcab00 0x400d93c9:0x3ffcad80 0x400d943f:0x3ffcadc0 0x400d94ce:0x3ffcae00 0x4016e30d:0x3ffcae20 0x400dab06:0x3ffcae40 0x400dbddb:0x3ffcae70 0x400dbffb:0x3ffcaee0 0x400d5949:0x3ffcaf00 0x400d63e0:0x3ffcb3b0 0x400ddd91:0x3ffcbc10
```

And here is the Decoded stack:

```
0x4012d2c5: mbedtls_sha512_software_process at /Users/ficeto/Desktop/ESP32/ESP32S2/esp-idf-public/components/mbedtls/port/sha/parallel_engine/esp_sha512.c line 292
0x4012e23e: mbedtls_internal_sha512_process at /Users/ficeto/Desktop/ESP32/ESP32S2/esp-idf-public/components/mbedtls/port/sha/parallel_engine/esp_sha512.c line 252
0x4012e2b3: mbedtls_sha512_update_ret at /Users/ficeto/Desktop/ESP32/ESP32S2/esp-idf-public/components/mbedtls/port/sha/parallel_engine/esp_sha512.c line 367
0x4012e2ed: mbedtls_sha512_update_ret at /Users/ficeto/Desktop/ESP32/ESP32S2/esp-idf-public/components/mbedtls/port/sha/parallel_engine/esp_sha512.c line 342
0x4012a3d4: mbedtls_sha512_ret at /Users/ficeto/Desktop/ESP32/ESP32S2/esp-idf-public/components/mbedtls/mbedtls/library/sha512.c line 461
0x40124912: entropy_update at /Users/ficeto/Desktop/ESP32/ESP32S2/esp-idf-public/components/mbedtls/mbedtls/library/entropy.c line 184
0x40124a0a: entropy_gather_internal at /Users/ficeto/Desktop/ESP32/ESP32S2/esp-idf-public/components/mbedtls/mbedtls/library/entropy.c line 289
0x40124a56: mbedtls_entropy_func at /Users/ficeto/Desktop/ESP32/ESP32S2/esp-idf-public/components/mbedtls/mbedtls/library/entropy.c line 369
0x40124bd9: mbedtls_entropy_func at /Users/ficeto/Desktop/ESP32/ESP32S2/esp-idf-public/components/mbedtls/mbedtls/library/entropy.c line 338
0x401208d5: mbedtls_ctr_drbg_reseed_internal at /Users/ficeto/Desktop/ESP32/ESP32S2/esp-idf-public/components/mbedtls/mbedtls/library/ctr_drbg.c line 380
0x401209b6: mbedtls_ctr_drbg_reseed at /Users/ficeto/Desktop/ESP32/ESP32S2/esp-idf-public/components/mbedtls/mbedtls/library/ctr_drbg.c line 418
0x40120a95: mbedtls_ctr_drbg_random_with_add at /Users/ficeto/Desktop/ESP32/ESP32S2/esp-idf-public/components/mbedtls/mbedtls/library/ctr_drbg.c line 536
0x40120b69: mbedtls_ctr_drbg_random at /Users/ficeto/Desktop/ESP32/ESP32S2/esp-idf-public/components/mbedtls/mbedtls/library/ctr_drbg.c line 603
0x4011e28e: mpi_fill_random_internal at /Users/ficeto/Desktop/ESP32/ESP32S2/esp-idf-public/components/mbedtls/mbedtls/library/bignum.c line 2501
0x4011f22b: mbedtls_mpi_random at /Users/ficeto/Desktop/ESP32/ESP32S2/esp-idf-public/components/mbedtls/mbedtls/library/bignum.c line 2594
0x40121c38: ecp_randomize_jac at /Users/ficeto/Desktop/ESP32/ESP32S2/esp-idf-public/components/mbedtls/mbedtls/library/ecp.c line 1719
0x40122911: ecp_mul_comb at /Users/ficeto/Desktop/ESP32/ESP32S2/esp-idf-public/components/mbedtls/mbedtls/library/ecp.c line 2084
0x401230c7: mbedtls_ecp_mul_restartable at /Users/ficeto/Desktop/ESP32/ESP32S2/esp-idf-public/components/mbedtls/mbedtls/library/ecp.c line 2761
0x401210ef: mbedtls_ecdh_compute_shared at /Users/ficeto/Desktop/ESP32/ESP32S2/esp-idf-public/components/mbedtls/mbedtls/library/ecdh.c line 127
0x40121336: mbedtls_ecdh_calc_secret at /Users/ficeto/Desktop/ESP32/ESP32S2/esp-idf-public/components/mbedtls/mbedtls/library/ecdh.c line 685
0x4011be1d: mbedtls_ssl_handshake_client_step at /Users/ficeto/Desktop/ESP32/ESP32S2/esp-idf-public/components/mbedtls/mbedtls/library/ssl_cli.c line 3753
0x40119881: mbedtls_ssl_handshake_step at /Users/ficeto/Desktop/ESP32/ESP32S2/esp-idf-public/components/mbedtls/mbedtls/library/ssl_tls.c line 5770
0x401198bb: mbedtls_ssl_handshake at /Users/ficeto/Desktop/ESP32/ESP32S2/esp-idf-public/components/mbedtls/mbedtls/library/ssl_tls.c line 5808
0x400d9af1: start_ssl_client(sslclient_context*, IPAddress const&, unsigned int, char const*, int, char const*, bool, char const*, char const*, char const*, char const*, bool, char const**) at /Users/martin/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp32/hardware/esp32/2.0.11/libraries/WiFiClientSecure/src/ssl_client.cpp line 271
0x400d93c9: WiFiClientSecure::connect(IPAddress, unsigned short, char const*, char const*, char const*, char const*) at /Users/martin/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp32/hardware/esp32/2.0.11/libraries/WiFiClientSecure/src/WiFiClientSecure.cpp line 140
0x400d943f: WiFiClientSecure::connect(char const*, unsigned short, char const*, char const*, char const*) at /Users/martin/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp32/hardware/esp32/2.0.11/cores/esp32/Printable.h line 33
0x400d94ce: WiFiClientSecure::connect(char const*, unsigned short) at /Users/martin/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp32/hardware/esp32/2.0.11/libraries/WiFiClientSecure/src/WiFiClientSecure.cpp line 117
0x4016e30d: WiFiClientSecure::connect(char const*, unsigned short, int) at /Users/martin/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp32/hardware/esp32/2.0.11/libraries/WiFiClientSecure/src/WiFiClientSecure.cpp line 122
0x400dab06: HTTPClient::connect() at /Users/martin/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp32/hardware/esp32/2.0.11/cores/esp32/WString.h line 339
0x400dbddb: HTTPClient::sendRequest(char const*, unsigned char*, unsigned int) at /Users/martin/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp32/hardware/esp32/2.0.11/libraries/HTTPClient/src/HTTPClient.cpp line 601
0x400dbffb: HTTPClient::GET() at /Users/martin/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp32/hardware/esp32/2.0.11/libraries/HTTPClient/src/HTTPClient.cpp line 518
0x400d5949: getPumpInfo() at /Users/martin/Library/CloudStorage/Dropbox/ErabliTEK/Martin/Arduino/LILYGO_POE_TEST/LILYGO_POE_TEST.ino line 204
0x400d63e0: loop() at /Users/martin/Library/CloudStorage/Dropbox/ErabliTEK/Martin/Arduino/LILYGO_POE_TEST/LILYGO_POE_TEST.ino line 307
0x400ddd91: loopTask(void*) at /Users/martin/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp32/hardware/esp32/2.0.11/cores/esp32/main.cpp line 50
```

And here is the code:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
// #include <ETH.h>
#include <ETHClass.h>       //Is to use the modified ETHClass
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SD.h>
#include "utilities.h"          //Board PinMap

#include <WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClientSecure.h>
#include <HTTPClient.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>

WiFiClientSecure client;
HTTPClient https;

String AIOHTTP_SESSION = "";
bool loggedIn = false;
unsigned long lastFetch;

//Change to IP and DNS corresponding to your network, gateway
IPAddress staticIP(192, 168, 202, 8);
IPAddress gateway(192, 168, 202, 1);
IPAddress subnet(255, 255, 255, 0);
IPAddress dns(192, 168, 202, 1);

static bool eth_connected = false;

#define TXD1 02
#define RXD1 14

float atmos = 28.0;
char pumpInfo[1024];
char sentPumpInfo[1024];
char trends[1024];

void WiFiEvent(WiFiEvent_t event)
{
    switch (event) {
    case ARDUINO_EVENT_ETH_START:
        Serial.println("ETH Started");
        //set eth hostname here
        ETH.setHostname("esp32-ethernet");
        break;
    case ARDUINO_EVENT_ETH_CONNECTED:
        Serial.println("ETH Connected");
        break;
    case ARDUINO_EVENT_ETH_GOT_IP:
        Serial.print("ETH MAC: ");
        Serial.print(ETH.macAddress());
        Serial.print(", IPv4: ");
        Serial.print(ETH.localIP());
        if (ETH.fullDuplex()) {
            Serial.print(", FULL_DUPLEX");
        }
        Serial.print(", ");
        Serial.print(ETH.linkSpeed());
        Serial.println("Mbps");
        eth_connected = true;
        loggedIn = false;
        break;
    case ARDUINO_EVENT_ETH_DISCONNECTED:
        Serial.println("ETH Disconnected");
        eth_connected = false;
        break;
    case ARDUINO_EVENT_ETH_STOP:
        Serial.println("ETH Stopped");
        eth_connected = false;
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}

void startPump(){
  https.begin(client, "https://192.168.202.10/api/pump/start");
  https.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  https.addHeader("Cookie", AIOHTTP_SESSION);
  int httpsResponseCode = https.POST("{}");
  if(httpsResponseCode == 200){
    Serial.println("Succefully started the pump!");
  }else{
    Serial.print("HTTPS Response code: ");
    Serial.println(httpsResponseCode);
    String response = https.getString();
    Serial.print(response);
    Serial.println();
  }
  https.end();
}

void stopPump(){
  https.begin(client, "https://192.168.202.10/api/pump/stop");
  https.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  https.addHeader("Cookie", AIOHTTP_SESSION);
  int httpsResponseCode = https.POST("{}");
  if(httpsResponseCode == 200){
    Serial.println("Succefully stopped the pump!");
  }else{
    Serial.print("HTTPS Response code: ");
    Serial.println(httpsResponseCode);
    String response = https.getString();
    Serial.print(response);
    Serial.println();
  }
  https.end();
}

void getPressureSetPoint(){
  https.begin(client, "https://192.168.202.10/api/pressure-setpoint");
  https.addHeader("Cookie", AIOHTTP_SESSION);
  unsigned long _start = millis();
  int httpsResponseCode = https.GET();
  if(httpsResponseCode == 200){
    Serial.print("Succefully fetched Pressure Setpoint in: ");
    Serial.print(millis() - _start);
    Serial.println(" ms");
    String response = https.getString();
    DynamicJsonDocument _doc(2048);
    DeserializationError err = deserializeJson(_doc, response);
    if(err == DeserializationError::Ok){
      DynamicJsonDocument _tmp(sizeof(pumpInfo));
      err = deserializeJson(_tmp, pumpInfo);
      _tmp["pressureSetpoint"] = serialized(String(atmos - (_doc["value"].as<float>() / 33.8639), 1));
      char buf[sizeof(pumpInfo)];
      serializeJson(_tmp, buf);
      strcpy(pumpInfo, buf);
    }
  }else{
    Serial.print("Error fetching Pressure Setpoint: ");
    Serial.print("HTTPS Response code: ");
    Serial.println(httpsResponseCode);
    String response = https.getString();
    Serial.print(response);
    Serial.println();
  }
  https.end();
}

void getPumpInfo(){
  https.begin(client, "https://192.168.202.10/api/pump-info");
  https.addHeader("Cookie", AIOHTTP_SESSION);
  unsigned long _start = millis();
  int httpsResponseCode = https.GET();
  if(httpsResponseCode == 200){
    Serial.print("Succefully fetched Pump Info in: ");
    Serial.print(millis() - _start);
    Serial.println(" ms");
    String response = https.getString();
    DynamicJsonDocument _doc(3072);
    DeserializationError err = deserializeJson(_doc, response);
    if(err == DeserializationError::Ok){
      DynamicJsonDocument _tmp(sizeof(pumpInfo));
      err = deserializeJson(_tmp, pumpInfo);
      _tmp["name"] = _doc["name"];
      _tmp["model"] = _doc["model"];
      _tmp["serial"] = _doc["serialNumber"];
      _tmp["status"] = _doc["status"];
      _tmp["runningHours"] = _doc["runningHours"];
      char buf[sizeof(pumpInfo)];
      serializeJson(_tmp, buf);
      strcpy(pumpInfo, buf);
    }else{
      Serial.print("deserializeJson() returned ");
      Serial.println(err.c_str());
    }
  }else if(httpsResponseCode == -11){
    lastFetch = lastFetch - 5000;
  }else{
    Serial.print("Error fetching Pump Info: ");
    Serial.print("HTTPS Response code: ");
    Serial.println(httpsResponseCode);
    String response = https.getString();
    Serial.print(response);
    Serial.println();
  }
  https.end();
}

void setAtmos(float value){
  atmos = value;
  https.begin(client, "https://192.168.202.10/api/atmospheric-pressure");
  https.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  https.addHeader("Cookie", AIOHTTP_SESSION);
  DynamicJsonDocument doc(200);
  doc["unitId"] = 23;
  doc["value"] = atmos;
  char payload[200];
  serializeJson(doc, payload, sizeof(payload));
  int httpsResponseCode = https.POST(payload);
  if(httpsResponseCode == 200){
    Serial.print("setAtmos setted to: ");
    Serial.print(atmos);
    Serial.println(" InHg!");
    //Setting gauge pressure!!
    doc.clear();
    doc["active"] = true;
    serializeJson(doc, payload, sizeof(payload));
    https.setURL("https://192.168.202.10/api/gauge-pressure");
    httpsResponseCode = https.POST(payload);
    if(httpsResponseCode == 200){
      Serial.println("Gauge pressure set succesfully!");
    }else{
      Serial.print("Error setting gauge pressure: ");
      Serial.print(httpsResponseCode);
      Serial.print(" with value: ");
      Serial.println(payload);
    }
  }
  https.end();
}

void setup(){
    Serial.begin(115200);
    Serial1.begin(115200, SERIAL_8N1, RXD1, TXD1);
    client.setInsecure();
    WiFi.onEvent(WiFiEvent);

#ifdef ETH_POWER_PIN
    pinMode(ETH_POWER_PIN, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(ETH_POWER_PIN, HIGH);
#endif


#if CONFIG_IDF_TARGET_ESP32
    if (!ETH.begin(ETH_ADDR, ETH_RESET_PIN, ETH_MDC_PIN,
                   ETH_MDIO_PIN, ETH_TYPE, ETH_CLK_MODE)) {
        Serial.println("ETH start Failed!");
    }
#else
    if (!ETH.beginSPI(ETH_MISO_PIN, ETH_MOSI_PIN, ETH_SCLK_PIN, ETH_CS_PIN, ETH_RST_PIN, ETH_INT_PIN)) {
        Serial.println("ETH start Failed!");
    }
#endif

    if (ETH.config(staticIP, gateway, subnet, dns, dns) == false) {
        Serial.println("Configuration failed.");
    }

}
unsigned int functionID = 0;
void loop(){
  if (eth_connected) {
    if((millis() - lastFetch) >= 500){
      switch(functionID){
        case 0:
          getPumpInfo();
          break;
        case 1:
          getPressureSetPoint();
          break;
      }
      functionID++;
      if(functionID > 1){
        functionID = 0;
      }
      lastFetch = millis();
    }
  }
  if(strcmp(pumpInfo, sentPumpInfo) != 0){
    Serial.println(pumpInfo);
    Serial1.print(pumpInfo);
    strcpy(sentPumpInfo, pumpInfo);
  }
  if(Serial1.available()){
    StaticJsonDocument<2048> doc;
    DeserializationError err = deserializeJson(doc, Serial1);
    if(err == DeserializationError::Ok){
      if(doc.containsKey("command")){
        if(doc["command"] == "startPump"){
          startPump();
        }else if(doc["command"] == "stopPump"){
          stopPump();
        }else if(doc["command"] == "setAtmos"){
          setAtmos(doc["value"]);
        }
      }
      serializeJson(doc, Serial);
      Serial.println();
    }else{
      Serial.print("deserializeJson() returned ");
      Serial.println(err.c_str());
    }
  }
}
```

And here is the data i try to retrieve in json:

```
{"name": "Shop", "location": null, "notes": null, "serialNumber": "API854338", "controllerSerial": "S5204001517", "model": "GHS350VSD+", "brand": "AtlasCopco", "productName": "HEX@", "status": "Off", "runningHours": 4, "commissioningDate": "2023-01-20T11:35:20.0Z", "datetime": "2023-08-21T15:02:18.860279+00:00", "hlpFeatures": [], "llpFeatures": [], "contactPhone": null, "contactEmail": null, "contactEntity": null, "loadCounters": {"load": 0.0, "time1to20": 6956.10009765625, "time20to40": 6353.2998046875, "time40to60": 703.5999755859375, "time60to80": 330.79998779296875, "time80to100": 2112.60009765625, "ratio1to20": 42.26987838745117, "ratio20to40": 38.60668182373047, "ratio40to60": 4.276423931121826, "ratio60to80": 2.010370969772339, "ratio80to100": 12.842491149902344}, "modelVersion": "v111", "containerVersions": [{"name": "netx90", "version": "0.1.0"}, {"name": "yocto", "version": "0.7.0"}, {"name": "llp", "version": "60793910172e1a27f5a9eb9c-710-001-5fee0bb632c7e68bda513826b3144484bffac665"}, {"name": "v111", "version": "0.12.15"}, {"name": "opcua", "version": "0.3.1"}, {"name": "centralcontroller", "version": "0.3.7"}, {"name": "value-wheel", "version": "0.3.9"}, {"name": "webui-cms-import-v111", "version": "0.2.39-15"}, {"name": "teamviewer", "version": "0.2.1"}, {"name": "iot-client", "version": "0.5.15"}, {"name": "composer", "version": "0.4.3"}, {"name": "webui-scheduler", "version": "0.2.39-15"}, {"name": "webui-front", "version": "0.2.39-15"}, {"name": "webui-api", "version": "0.2.39-15"}, {"name": "llp-interface", "version": "2579fd3d"}, {"name": "proxy-intern", "version": "0.3.2"}, {"name": "proxy", "version": "0.3.4"}, {"name": "database-postgres", "version": "0.2.0"}, {"name": "broker-extern", "version": "0.2.0"}, {"name": "updater", "version": "0.3.24-5"}, {"name": "system-manager", "version": "0.5.8-3"}, {"name": "broker", "version": "0.2.0"}, {"name": "docker-ui", "version": "0.4.0"}], "pressureSetpointPresent": true}
```

The GET call for this data is very long! It take about 4000ms in average!

Does anyone know what i am doing wrong ??

Thanx a lot!

Comment: Don't you have to explicitly free the storage assigned to a DynamicJsonDocument as used say in getPumpInfo(). See  https://arduinojson.org/v6/how-to/reuse-a-json-document/

Comment: I don't reuse the json document i recreate it each time! And the error happend before i create the json document!! The error happen on a GET call!

Comment: Ok, so, this is likely due to your stack not being big enough. Every time a function call is made, information needs to be pushed onto the stack. It'll be popped off when that function call returns. When you call into a library - you're calling a function. When that library function calls a function, it uses the same exact stack. Most likely, your stack is not big enough. Increase your stack size.

Comment: Also, make sure you're not making a recursive call ;)

Comment: This could also happen if you have a stray pointer and happen to modify the canary value stored in the stack. This value is periodically checked to see if it changes - IT SHOULD NEVER CHANGE - but it did. You could have your own bug that's causing this to happen, even though the stack may be the proper size. What I described above is what happens when you push something onto a full stack - it *must* overwrite that value, which will trigger what you're seeing.

Comment: Could this be done directly without using `buf` and save 1k stack space `char buf[sizeof(pumpInfo)]; serializeJson(_tmp, buf); strcpy(pumpInfo, buf);` ?
This also has what appears to be an unnecessary intermediate variable `String response = https.getString(); Serial.print(response);` possibly fragmenting heap storage. Maybe also look here because the data sizes in your program are huge: https://arduinojson.org/v6/how-to/reduce-memory-usage/. Some systems also impose a limit on the maximum URL size for HTTP GET. The stack size of the ESP32 is also limited and further reduced by heap growth.

Comment: The json object you shown has nothing related to the data you are trying to desrialize in the `getPumpInfo()`, so what exactly is the json object (before you are trying to deserialize it) that you received? how long is it? Also if you want others to help, trim down your code to the minimum reproducible code, and only show that code...